# How to setup multi-host networking with docker swarm on multiple remote machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Before asking this question I have read quiet of articles and stackoverflow questions but I couldn't get the right answer for my setup(perhaps it is already answered). Here is the architecture I have been struggling to get it to work.

1. I have three physical machines and I would like to setup the Docker swarm with multi-host networking so that I can run docker-compose.

For example:

1. Machine 1(Docker Swarm Manager and Contains Consoul)(192.168.5.11)
2. Machine 2(Docker Swarm Node)(192.168.5.12)
3. Machine 3 (Docker Swarm Node)(192.168.5.13)

And I need to run docker-compose from any other separate machine.

I have tried [Docker article](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/#/overlay-networking-with-an-external-key-value-store) but in that article it is all setup under the same physical machine using docker-machine and virtual box. How can I achieve above in three remote machines. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The latest version of Docker has [Swarm Mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-mode/) built in, so you don't need Consul.

To set up on your boxes, make sure they all have `docker version` of 1.12 or higher and then you just need to initialise the swarm and join it.

On Machine 1 run:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.5.11
```

The output from that will tell you the command to run on Machine 2 and 3 to join them to the swarm. You'll have a unique swarm token, and the command is something like:

```
docker swarm join \
--token SWMTKN-1-49nj1... \
192.168.5.11:2377
```

Now you have a 3-node swarm. Back on Machine 1 you can create a multi-host overlay network:

```
docker network create -d overlay my-app
```

And then you run workloads in the network by [deploying services](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/). If you want to use Compose with Swarm Mode, you need to use [distributed application bundles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/) - which are currently only in the experimental build of Docker.

Comment: Thanks Elton for the answer. I am already using Compose and I don't want to use distributed application bundles. Is there way to setup compose on swarm mode with virtual machines on different hosts?

Comment: Compose doesn't support swarm mode yet - basically compose just does `docker run` so if you use it everything will run on one node in the swarm. [This project](https://github.com/ddrozdov/docker-compose-swarm-mode) is worth a look - it takes a Compose YAML and uses `service create` to work with swarm mode.

Answer (score 4):

I figured this needs an update, as docker compose files are supported in docker swarm

1. Initialize the swarm on Machine 1 using

   ```
   docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.5.11
   ```
2. Join the swarm from Machine 2 & 3 using

   ```
   docker swarm join \
   --token <swarm token from previous step> 192.168.5.11:2377 \
   --advertise-addr eth0
   ```

   - eth0 is the network interface on machines 2 & 3, & could be different
     based on your config. I found that without the `--advertise-addr`
     option, containers couldn't talk to each other across hosts.
3. To list all the nodes in the swarm & see their status

   ```
   docker node ls
   ```
4. After this, deploy the stack (group of services or containers) from a compose file

   ```
   docker stack deploy -c <compose-file> my-app
   ```

   - This will create all the containers across multiple hosts
   - To list services (containers) on the swarm run `docker service ls`

See docker docs [Getting started with swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/)