# Use docker-compose with docker swarm

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using `docker 1.12.1`
I have an easy docker-compose script.

```
version: '2'

services:
  jenkins-slave:
    build: ./slave
    image: jenkins-slave:1.0
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "22"
    environment:
     - "constraint:NODE==master1"
  jenkins-master:
    image: jenkins:2.7.1
    container_name: jenkins-master
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "50000"
    environment:
     - "constraint:NODE==node1"
```

I run this script with `docker-compose -p jenkins up -d`.
This Creates my 2 containers but only on my master (from where I execute my command). I would expect that one would be created on the master and one on the node.
I also tried to add

```
networks:
  jenkins_swarm:
    driver: overlay
```

and

```
  networks:
     - jenkins_swarm
```

After every service but this is failing with:

```
Cannot create container for service jenkins-master: network jenkins_jenkins_swarm not found
```

While the network is created when I perform `docker network ls`

Someone who can help me to deploy 2 containers on my 2 nodes with docker-compose. Swarm is defenitly working on my "cluster". I followed [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/scale-service/) tutorial to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose doesn't support Swarm Mode at the moment.

When you run `docker compose up` on the master node, Compose issues `docker run` commands for the services in the Compose file, rather than `docker service create` - which is why the containers all run on the master. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844880/how-to-setup-multi-host-networking-with-docker-swarm-on-multiple-remote-machines/39850352#39850352) for options.

On the second point, networks are scoped in `1.12`. If you inspect your network you'll find it's been created at swarm-level, but Compose is running engine-level containers which can't see the swarm network.

Comment: I came here with the same question. The documentation for Compose say that it *does* support Swarm. However, either there is a huge chunk of documentation working (e.g. how do you define replicas?) or it's incorrect? https://docs.docker.com/compose/swarm/

Answer (score 0):

- We can do this with docker compose v3 now.

  https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/#feature-highlights
  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
- You have to initialize the swarm cluster using command

  `$ docker swarm init`
- You can add more nodes as worker or manager -

  https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/join-nodes/
- Once you have your both nodes added to the cluster, pass your compose v3 i.e deployment file to create a stack. Compose file should just contain predefined images, you can't give a Dockerfile for deployment in Swarm mode.

  `$ docker stack deploy -c dev-compose-deploy.yml --with-registry-auth PL`
- View your stack services status -

`$ docker stack services PL`

- Try to use Labels & Placement constraints to put services on different nodes.

Example "dev-compose-deploy.yml" file for your reference

```
version: "3"

services:

  nginx:
    image: nexus.example.com/pl/nginx-dev:latest
    extra_hosts:
      - "dev-pldocker-01:10.2.0.42”
      - "int-pldocker-01:10.2.100.62”
      - "prd-plwebassets-01:10.2.0.62”
    ports:
      - "80:8003"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - logs:/app/out/
    networks:
      - pl
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      labels:
        feature.description: “Frontend”
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]
    command: "/usr/sbin/nginx"

  viz:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer
    ports:
      - "8085:8080"
    networks:
      - pl
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        feature.description: "Visualizer"
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
pl:

volumes:
logs:
```