# RabbitMQ cluster by docker-compose on different hosts and different projects

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have 3 projects, that deploys on different hosts. Every project have it's own RabbitMQ container. But I need to create cluster with this 3 hosts, using the same vhost, but different user/login pair.

I was tried Swarm and overlay networks, but swarm is aimed to run solo containers and with compose it doesn't work. Also, I was tried docker-compose bundle, but this is not work as expected :(

**I assumed that it would work something like this**:

1) On manager node I create overlay network

2) In every compose file I extend networks config for rabbitmq container with my overlay network.

3) They work as expected and I don't publish to Internet rabbitmq port.

---

Any idea, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right, but [Docker Compose doesn't work with Swarm Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875575/use-docker-compose-with-docker-swarm/39875980#39875980) at the moment. Compose just runs `docker` commands, so you could script up what you want instead. For each project you'd have a script like this:

```
docker network create -d overlay app1-net
docker service create --network app1-net --name rabbit-app1 rabbitmq:3
docker service create --network app1-net --name app1 your-app-1-image
...
```

When you run all three scripts on the manager, you'll have three networks, each network will have its own RabbitMQ service (just 1 container by default, use `--replicas` to run more than one). Within the network other services can reach the message queue by the DNS name `rabbit-appX`. You don't need to publish any ports, so Rabbit is not accessible outside of the Docker network.

Comment: So you mean, that I need to run every container, defined in my compose-file as service by `docker service create` command? Ok... But what about volumes? For example, for MariaDB or Redis, which used on one of the projects?

Comment: You can do that with the `--mount` option in [docker service create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#/differences-between---mount-and---volume). Be mindful that your containers will move around if a host goes down, so you'll want a shared volume driver.

Comment: Thanks for useful link. I think, it is solution for my question. Not very convenient... But it should work.
What about `docker-compose bundle` and `docker deploy` (I have installed Docker 1.12.2-rc2)? It works the same?