# How to use Docker Compose with legacy Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I am trying to deploy my app with `Compose` and `Swarm`. Currently I don't want to upgrade my `docker-compose.yaml` from `v2` to `v3`. So I am only able to do that with `standalone(legacy) swarm` rather that `docker swarm mode` based on Stoneman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875575/use-docker-compose-with-docker-swarm) and official Swarm documents.

Following the [official instruction](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/), I successfully set up a swarm cluster. I ran `docker -H :4000 info` on the `swarm manager` node to check the swarm cluster status,  as shown below. There are two other worker nodes in this cluster. Next, I want to `create` an overlay network with this cluster and refer this network in the `docker-compose.yaml`. But when I ran `docker -H :4000 network create -d overlay test` on the swarm manager node to create the netwrok, it reported error: `Error response from daemon: Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.`

So, how can I create a network with a swarm cluster( without `docker-machine` and `virtual box`)? Currently, the swarm manager and worker nodes are running as docker containers.
[image]

Comment: Chalex have you read through @Bret's answer. Is swarm classic is your requirement?

Comment: Jinna, I have turned to Docker Swarm Mode and I solved my problem. I just wanted to know how to set up an overlay network with classic Docker Swarm. I thought there would be some detailed instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup overlay networking with it's own etcd backend first? https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay-standalone.swarm/

Swarm "classic" is deprecated and replaced by docker swarm mode. Everything is harder in classic, including setting up overlay. I wouldn't recommend using it for anything new unless you had a hard requirement.

Comment: yeah, I tried to setup the overlay network with classic Swarm. But I failed to make it. Then I turned to Docker Swarm Mode and solved my problem. So is it possible to setup an overlay network with the Classic Swarm? Is it always this obscure and difficult to setup an overlay network with Classic Swarm?

Comment: Yes because Classic Swarm only existed for 1.5 years before it was replaced with Swarm Mode. It didn't receive any further features or community love after that, because Swarm Mode solved most of the same problem with much less effort.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In swarm mode you run all commands at the swarm manager host. Same with creating networks, secrets, etc.
You can find out the docker manager machine by:
$docker node ls
Manager host is marked with MANAGER STATUS:Leader.
After creating the network on the manager all nodes on that swarm should see the network.

"I ran docker -H :4000 network create -d overlay test"
Better to declare the network inside the stack yml file, for faster and easier deployment. you can create network and expose your ports at the yml file, no need to create them manually every time you run the stack.
Add the following block under the docker service:

```
services:
...
#Network
   networks:
    - network-name-here
...
#Exposed ports:
  ports:
    - target: 4000 
      published: 4000
```

At the end of the yml file add the following block to declare the network, so its created every time you run $docker stack deploy:

```
networks:
  network-name-here:
   driver: overlay
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But actually I didn't use `swarm mode`. I set up a swarm cluster with `classic swarm`, aka `standalone` or  `legacy` swarm. For `swarm mode`, I didn't encounter any problems.